# Can Site Recycle Bin not empty item automatically after 14 days?

Tags: recycle-bin

Is there a way to setup the site Recycle Bin that it will not automatically delete items more than 14 days old?

Answer (score 3):

This setting is controlled in Central Administration.

- Go to Manage Web Applications under Application Management.
- Select the Web Application for which you want to edit the setting and click on General Settings on the Ribbon.
- Set whatever values you want:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When a user deletes an item, the item is automatically sent to the first-stage Recycle Bin. By default, when an item is deleted from the first-stage Recycle Bin, the item is sent to the second-stage Recycle Bin. A site collection administrator can restore items from the second-stage Recycle Bin.

As Paul mentioned in his answer how to configure it. By default it is 60 days for 1st stage recyclbin and 50% of the site collection quota for 2nd stage.

[Plan to protect content by using recycle bins and versioning](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263011.aspx)

http://www.sharepoint2013.me/Blog/Post/239/Configure-Recycle-Bin-and-alert-settings-in-SharePoint